# Insert new rows in CellForRowAt

Tags: swift, uitableview

I currently have a table that I dynamically populate from some stored arrays:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    allAlbums = LibraryAPI.shared.getCases()

    // Filter the main array to match a single case
    allAlbums = allAlbums.filter { $0.title == title}

    // Get data to fill in to table
    sectionNames = [ "Trainee Information", "Patient Information", "Examiner Information" ];
    sectionItems = [ [allAlbums[0].doctor], [allAlbums[0].patient], [allAlbums[0].markscheme]]

    // Autoresize rows
    tableView.rowHeight = UITableView.automaticDimension
    tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 500

    // Remove excess row seperators
    tableView.tableFooterView = UIView()
    tableView.separatorColor = UIColor.clear

    titleText.text = title


}
```

The data stored in the 'markscheme' portion is going to be a long bit of text with breaks that I can then break it when loading the table - with the aim of each of these new strings creating a new row in the table. At the moment, I only have the basic 6 rows being created:

```
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 3
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if (self.expandedSectionHeaderNumber == section) {
        let arrayOfItems = self.sectionItems[section] as! NSArray
        return arrayOfItems.count;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
    if (self.sectionNames.count != 0) {
        return self.sectionNames[section] as? String
    }
    return ""
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 44.0;
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForFooterInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat{
    return 0;
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplayHeaderView view: UIView, forSection section: Int) {
    //recast your view as a UITableViewHeaderFooterView
    let header: UITableViewHeaderFooterView = view as! UITableViewHeaderFooterView
    header.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.darkGray
    header.textLabel?.textColor = UIColor.white

    if let viewWithTag = self.view.viewWithTag(kHeaderSectionTag + section) {
        viewWithTag.removeFromSuperview()
    }
    let headerFrame = self.view.frame.size
    let theImageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: headerFrame.width - 32, y: 13, width: 18, height: 18));
    theImageView.image = UIImage(named: "Chevron-Dn-Wht")
    theImageView.tag = kHeaderSectionTag + section
    header.addSubview(theImageView)

    // make headers touchable
    header.tag = section
    let headerTapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer()
    headerTapGesture.addTarget(self, action: #selector(CaseViewController.sectionHeaderWasTouched(_:)))
    header.addGestureRecognizer(headerTapGesture)
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "tableCell", for: indexPath) as! CustomTableCell
    let section = self.sectionItems[indexPath.section] as! NSArray
    cell.textLabel?.textColor = UIColor.black

    // Header section
    let header = self.sectionNames[indexPath.section] as! String

    // If markscheme, create the markscheme format
    if (header == "Examiner Information") {

    }
    cell.textData?.text = section[indexPath.row] as! String

    return cell
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
}
```

As you can see, I'm detecting when the markscheme section is being loaded - how can I split the text in that title AND create new rows based on the number of values created (as this will be variable)?

Comment: You definitely must not make any attempt to update your data source or the table view in `cellForRowAt`.

Comment: What's the best way to go about this then?

Comment: You build a proper data model before the table view is loaded. Then all of the data source methods can returns the correct values based on the data model.